# Angular directive for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created this number format directive, but if I use it on more than one input, it doesn't work for all of them, but with only one it works. 
Any ideas?

```
directive('formatUsNumber', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        priority: 100,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            scope.formatNumber = function() {
                var n = element.val();
                var dest = n;
                if (n.length >= 10) {
                    if (/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/.test(n)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    dest = n.replace(/\D/g, '');
                    if (!isNaN(dest)) {
                        n = dest;
                    }
                    if (n.substr(0, 1) != "1") {
                        n = "1" + n;
                    }
                }
                element.val(n);
                ngModel.$setViewValue(n);
            };
        },
    };
});
```

The template:

```
<input type="text" ng-change="formatNumber()" format-us-number ng-model="myModel" />
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7479/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because scope of directive is not isolated.
And also I've made few changes, hope it workes the same

```
directive('formatUsNumber', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    priority: 100,
            scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        scope.formatNumber = function() {
            var n = ngModel.$modelValue;
            if (n.length >= 10) {
                if (/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/.test(n)) {
                    return;
                }
                n = n.replace(/\D/g, '');
                if (!isNaN(dest)) {
                    n = dest;
                }
                if (n.substr(0, 1) != "1") {
                    n = "1" + n;
                }

                ngModel.$setViewValue(n, 'change:directive');
            }
        };
    },
  };
});
```

U can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7486/)

Comment: Thanks, it actually did work on my fiddle, however on my app I got this error: `Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [formatUsNumber, offClick] asking for new/isolated scope`. Ideas?

Comment: @Brayan both directives needs isolate scope... Can u provide offClick directive body? maybe we can update it and remove usage of `isolate scope`?

Comment: @Brayan can u update `offClick` directive, as I see in their git, they've already fixed this [issue](https://github.com/TheSharpieOne/angular-off-click/issues/11)

Comment: Great, will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an isolated scope, something like this:

```
restrict: 'A',
require: 'ngModel',
priority: 100,
scope:{
    ngModel:'='
},...
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually did work on my fiddle, however on my app I got this error: `Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [formatUsNumber, offClick] asking for new/isolated scope`

Answer (score 1):

For this use case I think that fits better implements a **custom filter** instead a directive. 
[Building Custom AngularJS Filters](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters)
Other alternative could be incude a custom parser and/or formatter. 
 [AngularJS - Formatters and Parsers](https://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.